# Socket outputstream not flushing android

Tags: java, android, sockets, outputstream, socketserver

I am new to the Android world, and I'm trying to make a simple socket tcp server/client chat application. I am using twisted (python) for the server. Here is the source code:

```
from twisted.internet import reactor, protocol, endpoints
from twisted.protocols import basic
from twisted.internet.address import IPv4Address
import threading
import datetime, time

# Broadcast to all clients
def broadcast(clients, text):
    for c in clients:
        try:
            c.sendLine(text)
        except Exception:
            print '[!] Cannot send message to' + c.getIp()

# SocketServer class
class PubProtocol(basic.LineReceiver):
    def __init__(self, factory):
        self.factory = factory

    def connectionMade(self):
        ip = self.transport.getHost().host
        print "[+] Client {} connected".format(ip)
        self.factory.clients.add(self)

    def connectionLost(self, reason):
        self.factory.clients.remove(self)
        print '[+] Client disconnected'

    def lineReceived(self, line):
        # Get IP
        ip = self.transport.getHost().host
        # Get current time
        time = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S")
        # Build message to send
        text = "[{}] {}: {}".format(time, ip, line)
        # Print text to server
        print text

        # Broadcast to all clients
        broadcast(self.factory.clients, text)



class PubFactory(protocol.Factory):
    def __init__(self):
        self.clients = set()

    def buildProtocol(self, addr):
        return PubProtocol(self)

print '[+] Server started'      
endpoints.serverFromString(reactor, "tcp:1025").listen(PubFactory())
reactor.run()
```

I've tested it with telnet, and everything that I write in my telnet terminal, is shown in my server console, and also send back to the client.

All good until I started to code the client sending message part in java. Here is my sendMessage function:

```
private void sendMessage(String text) throws IOException {
    Log.d("ME", "In message function");
    if (!goodToGo) {
        Log.d("ME", "In: goodToGo = false");
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setMessage("Not connected to server.");
        builder.setTitle("Error");
        builder.show();
        return;
    }

    OutputStream outputStream = socket.getOutputStream();
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(outputStream);

    out.print(text);
    out.print("");
    out.flush();

    Log.d("ME", String.format("after message %s sent", text));
}
```

I call this function only after I connect to the server (100% sure!)

The problem is that I get nothing in my server console, after I send a message, even though logcat shows me the "after message some_message sent".
I've tried different ways to send the message, but all the same, the server doesn't print any message. I also tried to send **\n**, but same results. The server cannot be a problem, since it's working with telnet and also nc.

Comment: Don't create a new `PrintWriter` per message. Use the same one for the life of the socket. And send `\r\n` if the peer is reading Telnet-compatible lines.

Comment: no way ... the \r was missing. I've tried with \n but not with \r\n
Thanks man! Works in this way.